# Enable google maps api key in production environment

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made a flask app and deployed it to a linux server on Linode. It is running and some of my pages are working. For example, the contact page works. However, some of them have an inset google map. Upon loading one of these pages, my map is visible for a split second, then a big gray exclamation! and the map is blocked.

While testing the app using Flask's built in development server in my remote environment, all my functionality worked. When moving to a production environment, I used nginx and gunicorn. And I think I did it correctly. Judging that I do see the google maps working for just a second, it looks like this is not the issue.

Do I need to enable my google maps javascript api key for the production environment somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have a look at your source code, I see

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=None&callback=initMap
```

So, you did not add the API key, so it cannot work.

Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key for how to get a key.